# Which Wordpress files execute before my theme's functions.php on a rest api call?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I am having a problem that I have see reported here several times.

The response I am getting from a call to a custom rest api endpoint which I registered using register_rest_route within the rest_api_init hook ends up returning 4 spaces before my expected return value (i.e. responseText has spaces before it).

I saw several refences stating the this can be because of whitespace after the closing ?> in some .php file (and I accept that this is probably the case here as well).

I am trying to find **Which** file is causing this...

I know its some file that runs before my theme's functions.php file because if I prepenf ZZZ before the opening <?php of my functions.php the responseText has this ZZZ after the 4 spaces which I am trying to hunt down....

So the Q is which files run before my theme's functions.php  on a rest api call?
(also which is the first page that runs on such a call might be helpfull  or if there is some way to force wordpress to dump a list of all the pages that it loaded/included/imported ducing a call up until a call to die() )

UPDATE:
Following asking the Q I found the file \app\public\wp-load.php which when I placed echo statements in its beginning and end the extra spaces where in between those comments, so I did a process of repeated bisection until I got to a line where it was calling \app\public\wp-config.php did the same there and got to a call to \fictional-uni\app\public\wp-settings.php where in line 350 it loops over the files in the "must use" plugins folder ( \app\public\wp-content\mu-plugins\ ) where indeed was a file I created that had the 4 spaces at the end following a closing ?> which I now removed.

I am still leaving the Q open for a while in case someone can provide a smarter / faster way I could have used to find this file (I also though of using a search within visual code studio but was unable to create a proper regex to find this file...
If no better way would rise I will post my update as a an answer and accept it later.

Comment: Normally I’d tell you to install the [official troubleshooting plugin](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/) but unfortunately it doesn’t work in REST mode (AFAIK). So the other normal solution is to just disable all plugins, including MU, set to a core-provided theme, and find a way to run only your base code that is experiencing the problem. Your way is also a very common way to do this, too. Sometimes it is just easier hack core and throw `debug_backtrace` or similar in various places.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a json response instead of string response.

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['data'] = $data;
    echo json_encode($response);
    wp_die();
```

and on frontend

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajaxurl,
    cache: false,
    data: {
        action: action,
    },
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (response.status == "success") {
            console.log(response.data);
        } 
    },
```